# Excel format numbers with only the specificity needed: 1/2, 3/8, 7/16, etc

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of numbers in excel that I am using to help me with a carpentry project. Since I'm in the good 'ol USA I expect measurements like this:

- 4 5/8
- 4 1/2
- 4 3/4

I'm able to get the numbers to display as fractions, but I want them to be only as precise as the fraction requires. I don't need common denominators; in fact they make the reading of the file more cumbersome. Here's what I'm getting:

- 4 5/8
- 4 4/8
- 4 6/8

How can I get all the cells in that column to be formatted the most simply (e.g. with 1/2 instead of 4/8)? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please specify what have you tried to reach what you already have. Are the numbers you have really formatted as numbers or as text?

Comment: I have tried formatting the numbers in the Fraction Category with "Up to One Digit" (gave uncommon-to-carpentry denominators like 4 3/5), "Up to Two Digits" (even more weird: 4 23/38), and "As Eighths" which is working okay except I'd rather see 4 1/2 instead of 4 4/8. These are definitely numbers and not text; each cell is the result of a formula =B2-(F2*2)

Comment: @PeterBentley, Can you also please post the scale fractions in carpentry? The answer below by Mate Juhasz works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Round to 1/8s your result then apply fraction format "up to one digit":

`=ROUND(<formula>*8,0)/8`

Where `<formula>` is your original formula.

I don't know how you calculate in carpentry, you may want to use `ROUNDUP` to avoid calculating less then necessary.

Also, you may want to replace 8 to 16, 32 in the formula and display up to two digits.

Answer (score 1):

> #### I have numbers that are not integers,
>   and I want to round the fractional part to the nearest multiple of ⅛
>   and then reduce it to lowest terms.

If

- The above is an accurate description of your requirement,
- You’re willing to have one column to contain the actual number
  and another column to display the *display value*, and
- You’re willing to dedicate a few cells elsewhere in the workbook
  to a lookup table,

then this answer should work for you.

Create an array mapping all possible fractions
from their numeric forms to their textual (display) forms:

[image]
      Note that the non-blank text values (`R2`, `R3`, ...)
      all begin with a space.

Then, if cell `C1` contains a number, such as 4.62, set `D1` to

```
=INT(C1+Q$2/2) & VLOOKUP(MOD(C1+Q$2/2,1), Q$1:R$8, 2)
```

`Q2` contains the smallest representable fraction;
in the above example, it is ⅛ (0.125). 
So we want to add half of that to the `C1` value to allow for rounding;
we want anything between 4.94 and 5.06 to be displayed as “5”. 
Then `MOD(C1+Q$2/2,1)` extracts the fractional part of the augmented number,
and the `VLOOKUP` finds the textual form that you want to display.

This approach has the feature
that you aren’t restricted to a single sequence of fractions
e.g., the multiples of 1/8);
if you also want, say, multiples of 1/5 or 1/3, you can add them to the table.

Comment: Interesting approach! I think `& " "` is missing from your formula to separate integer part from fraction.

Comment: Actually, the text values `R2`, `R3`, ..., all begin with a space. I suppose I should have explained that.

Comment: Scott, thanks for this; it looks fairly ingenious and definitely is an angle I could see using in cases like this. I ended up using Máté's answer, but thanks for the time you put into illustrating and explaining your approach.